# reading result in java

Tags: java, sockets, url, https

Every time I am getting this error in my response while reading Google search result using socket, every time I search it gives me this error in response, sometimes it gives me 302 response, now it is giving me 301, I don't know what to do with it, I just only want to get the result from the Google and every time I get stuck here, How to sort it out :

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/search?q=java
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2013 10:57:46 GMT
Expires: Thu, 28 Mar 2013 10:57:46 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 232
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
301 Moved
The document has moved here
```

Here is my code :

```java
public String readGoogle(String keyword, int page) {
    String content = "";
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("google.com", 80);
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        p.print("GET /search?q=" + keyword + "&start=" + page
                + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        p.print("User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 "
              + "(compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)\r\n");
        p.print("Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            content += line;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put complete URL in your `GET` request:

```
 //           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 p.print("GET http://www.google.com/search?q=" + keyword + ...
 //           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 //           ADD THE FULL URL HERE
```

Maybe it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

A 301/302 means that the server is asking you to re-issue your request (redirected). To handle this read the 'Location' header from the response and then issue a new GET request to the URL from supplied from the server. In your example above you were being redirected to 'http://www.google.com/search?q=java'.

Alternatively you could pull down a library that handles redirection for you such as Apache Http Commons. Their tutorial can be read here [Tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

`www.google.com` redirects you to a country specific site based on your IP Adress

the `new location` also supplied, to which you need to create a socket.

Comment: please can u explain it, or can u please provide me sample code to resolve this problem.

Comment: If you can relax your `Socket` class requierement, you can use HttpClient from Apache to make life easier for you.